# Cakephp splitting long view.ctp into smaller ones

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

One of my view file in cake is getting very long, like 300+ lines already. And i find it very difficult to keep track of the understanding.

Is it a good idea to split them up into smaller files and then including them in the parent view file?

If its ok to be done,

1. In what extension should i create the smaller files? .ctp or .php?
2. Including them with require_once(view-child1.ext) should be fine, right?

Im fairly new to cakePHP. So i prefer advises from the experts over here. Please put me in the right direction.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the help guys.

I tried it. But i cant seem to pass the variable. echo $this->Element('reviews/view-goal',$history); Parent view shows and error saying undefined variable in that element.

Im calling the elements from this loop:

```
foreach($histories as $date => $history)
```

Cant pass $history. But $histories is being passed correctly.

Comment: You can simply pass the variable in an array. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element

Comment: If you want to use `$histories` variable into the element file, then you should pass `$histories` instead of `$history` from the view file.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was wrong about passing the variables. It's corrected, but you probably got it right from the accepted answer.

Comment: You pass variables into elements like this: $this->Element('reviews/view-goal', array('history'=>$history));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make elements in `View/Elements` folder with `.ctp` extension.

[This link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) would help you to make clean separation of your view files with the related/repeated code.

An element is basically a mini-view that can be included in other views, in layouts, and even within other elements. Elements can be used to make a view more readable, placing the rendering of repeating elements in its own file. They can also help you re-use content fragments in your application.

Elements live in the /app/View/Elements/ folder, and have the .ctp filename extension. They are output using the element method of the view:

```
<?php echo $this->element('helpbox'); //without extension ?>
```

You can pass variables from your view to the element.

In your view:

```
 <?php echo $this->Element('reviews/view-goal', array('history' => $history));
```

In view-goal.ctp element you can directly access `$history` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a very good idea. But don't use the normal `require()` of PHP.

CakePHP has a [feature called "elements"](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements), a mechanism to put parts of a view into separate `.ctp` files. The files go in a special folder, `View/Elements`

You can include an element like this:

```
echo $this->element('sidebar/recent_comments');
```

If you need any variables inside the element, you need to pass them in an additional array parameter:

```
echo $this->element('sidebar/recent_comments', array('variable_name' => /* Variable content */));
```

In order to keep your view files small, you should also make sure that you put stuff that is shared by most pages (header, footer) into the [Layout](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts) file. And obviously: keep JS and CSS in external files.